# Geodesics of Poincaré Ball Model

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I am asked to consider the Poincaré ball model of 3d hyperbolic space and characterize its geodesics. I.e. we have a pseudo-riemannan manifold $(M,g)$ where
$$
M = \{(x^1,x^2,x^3)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : \|x\|_{eucl}<1\} 
$$
is equipped with the metric
\begin{align*}
g=4\left(\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}\right)^2 (dx^1 \otimes dx^1+dx^2\otimes dx^2 + dx^3\otimes dx^3).
\end{align*}

---

More precisely,

1. I am asked to show that the lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are geodesics (by considering appropriate isometries) - I have no clue how to start here.
2. Using this I should somehow figure out how to show that the geodesic $c_V$ with $c_V(0)=0$ $\dot c_\xi (0) = V$ is given by
   \begin{align*}
   c_V(t) = \tanh(|V|t) \frac{V}{|V|}.
   \end{align*}

---

I do not know how to show 1. Neither do I have any clue of how to go from 1. to 2. I would appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: If you figure out the formula for the Levi-Civita connection, you can see directly that the unit tangent vector to such a line is parallel.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Thanks. This was my knee-jerk reaction as well, but this led me to the conclusion that I had to compute the Christoffel Symbols (maybe not??), which I kind of wanted to avoid (my understanding of the motivation for this questions is to teach us to be "smart" about computing geodesics - similar to the discussion in Lee's Riemannian Geometry pp 81-86).

Comment: Of course, spherical coordinates + Cartan's method of moving frames would be my natural approach ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fixed point set of an isometry is totally geodesic. See if you can show that rotations about lines passing through the origin are isometries.

Then solve the geodesic equation in one dimension along that line to arrive at a geodesic parametrization. (You can wlog assume that $V = (1, 0, 0)$ --- do you see why?)

Comment: thank you for the hint - I will try it out and report on any progress. 1. I don't exactly understand what you mean (I don't know any of the terms) by the first sentence "The zero set of an isometry is totally geodesic". Can this somehow be rephrased as the set of fixed points of an isometry contains a (maximal?) geodesic.

2. I'm guessing the wlog has something to do with rotation invariance of the metric...

Comment: The fixed-point set, thank you. If $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and $\phi:M\to M$ is an isometry, then $\{p\in M\ |\ p = \phi(p)\}$ is a totally geodesic submanifold. As for (2), yes. :)

Comment: OK, I have had some further time to think about this. I understand that rotations around a fixed axis gives an isometry and that the fixed point sets of (i.e. the lines through the origin) are thus geodesics. Solving the geodesic equation would mean I'd have to compute the Christoffel Symbols, which I would like to try to avoid. For instance for the sphere $S^2$ one can characterize the geodesics in a similar way without actually solving the geodesic equations. Is there a similar way to solve this problem?

Comment: To continue on the example of the sphere. There we know (by a similar argument) that the geodesics are contained in the intersection $S^2\cap H$ for some plane $H$, which leads us to geodesics of the form $c(t)= p \cos (\alpha t) + \sin (\alpha t) \frac{V}{\|V\|}$. One then just "solves" for $\alpha = \|V\|$. In the question I am asking we have similar amounts of information - except in the sphere case the trigonometric functions appear for obvious reasons, whereas I cannot say the same for $\tanh$ in my question...

Comment: If you work in polar coordinates, I seem to recall that the Christoffel symbols end up being pretty simple. You can separate the metric to something like $g = (\mbox{something})dx_{S^2}^2\otimes dr^2$ and use that to solve the differential equation.

Comment: If you want to follow the example of the sphere, you can use the fact that hyperbolic space can be realized as one of the sheets of the hyperboloid $\|u\|_{3,1} = 1$ in Minkowski space. Then geodesics are again the intersections of the hyperboloid with planes and you can reason as follows.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the $\tanh$ has something to do with relation between the euclidean radius and the hyperbolic radius. If the hyperbolic radius is $R$, then the Euclidean radius is $\tanh(R/2)$.